# How to inject ChangeDetectorRef service into pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I'm trying to inject the ChangeDetectorRef service into my pipe but when launch
the app this is my error : No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!

I have seen several examples of what i'm trying to do (Translate pipe or async pipe). But it's not working with mine...

Here is my pipe :

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {LangChangeEvent, TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable()
@Pipe({
    name: 'CollectionTranslation',
    pure: false
})

export class CollectionPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
    value: string;
    lastKey: string;

    onLangChange: Subject<LangChangeEvent>;

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private _ref:   ChangeDetectorRef) {

    }

    updateValue(key: string, lang: string) {
        this.value = this.collectionTranslation(key, lang);
        this.lastKey = key;
        this._ref.markForCheck();
    }

    transform(collectionParam: string) {
        // lang parameter is just here to execute the pipe each time the current lang is changed.
        // it's not used in the pipe

        if (this.lastKey === collectionParam) {
            return this.value;
        }

        this.updateValue(collectionParam, localStorage.getItem('kia.language'));

        if (!this.onLangChange) {
            this.onLangChange = this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
                if (this.lastKey) {
                    this.lastKey = null; // we want to make sure it doesn't return the same value until it's been updated
                    this.updateValue(collectionParam, event.lang);
                }
            });
        }

        return this.value;
    }

    private collectionTranslation(collectionParam: string, lang: string): string {
        let collection = '';
        if (collectionParam === null || collectionParam === undefined) {
            return '';
        }

        const coll = collectionParam.toUpperCase();
        if (lang === 'fr') {
            collection = coll.startsWith('E') || coll.startsWith('S') ? 'ETE ' : 'HIVER ';
        } else {
            // Lang EN
            collection = coll.startsWith('E') || coll.startsWith('S') ? 'SUMMER ' : 'WINTER ';
        }

        collection = collection + coll.substring(coll.length - 2);

        return collection;
    }

    _dispose(): void {
        if (typeof this.onLangChange !== 'undefined') {
            this.onLangChange.unsubscribe();
            this.onLangChange = undefined;
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._dispose();
    }
}
```

For me, there is no need to add the ChangeDetectorRef to the module since it is core.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use `ApplicationRef` instead of `ChangeDetectorRef` because the second one only see if in a specific component there are changes. Try doing same thing with the first one.

However, could you paste your Component.ts file where you have an example of using this pipe? Have you added in `providers` the pipe AND the Detector?

Hope will help

Comment: I need to use ChangeDetectorRef to get access to markForCheck().

In my ts file i just add the pipe to the constructor and call the transform method : this.collectionPipe.transform(row.gblId);

The pipe is in the providers of the module but there is nothing to add for the detector.

Comment: I use it like a standart pipe too ( {{myvar | CollectionPipe}} )

Comment: try adding the detector with the pipe in the declaration of your module

Comment: this is what i got :

  Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
      Type 'typeof KiaMaxValidator | typeof CollectionPipe | typeof GarmentBookingLetterService | typeof KiaA...' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
        Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
          Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'FactoryProvider'.
            Property 'provide' is missing in type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef'.

Comment: Don't forget that the way you use `ApplicationRef` will be different from the usage of `ChangeDetectorRef`: `this.applicationRef.tick();`